# Flutter Mocktail Error: No matching calls. All calls: method(Instance of Object)

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I am trying to verify if my method is called with the arguments I am interested in. However, it seems to be working only with primitive types. Instead of returning my object, it just says `Instance of MyAnswer`. Why does this happen?

```
test('Compute answers', () async {
    when(myService.submitAnswer(any, any)).thenAnswer((_) async {});
    final model = MyModel();
    model.submit(); // This calls myService.submitAnswer(MyAnswer(...), 123)).
    verify(myService.submitAnswer(MyAnswer(...), 123).called(1);
  });
```

This throws `No matching calls. All calls: MyService.submitAnswer(Instance of 'MyAnswer', 123)`.

Comment: 1. If you didn't implement `operator ==` and `hashCode` on your `MyAnswer` class, then two different instances will not compare equal. Consequently, `verify(myService.submitAnswer(MyAnswer(...), 123).called(1)` will never succeed because it will always be attempting to compare against a brand new instance. 2. If you didn't implement `toString()`, then when the verification fails, you'll end up with `'Instance of ...'` when `package:test` tries to print a diagnostic describing the failure.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I don't think I figured it out in the end, otherwise I would have closed this. But re-reading the question now, the previous comment seems to point in the right direction.

Comment: I had the same issue, for me the solution was to `await` the call that is being tested. So for your case you might need to `await` you call for `model..submit();`, assuming  it returns a `Future`.

The reason is that without `await` the `verify` is called to early.

Comment: @SEG.Veenstra, what about when you have another async in the function that you are awaiting?

Comment: @ClementOseiTano not really sure about what you mean, (it's been a while for me)
maybe the async matchers are what you are looking for?
https://pub.dev/packages/test#future-matchers

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem too, I was able to solve it using equatable package.
https://pub.dev/packages/equatable.

Let the model class extend equatable

```
class MyModel extends Equatable {
  final String email;
  final String mobile;

  MyModel({this.email = "", this.mobile = ""});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [email, mobile];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Phew! After 4-5 hours of spending found a solution..**

I am using a bloc with clean architecture. Below was the line that failed for me.

```
  verify(
    () => authBloc.add(
      Authenticate(
        authenticateUserParams: authParams,
      ),
    ),
  ).called(1);
```

If we observe then it depends on 2 things as mentioned below:

1. Authenticate Event
2. AuthenticateUserParams Model

I have added ***Equatable*** in my Authenticate event.

***But, I have not added Equatable to my AuthenticateUserParams model.***

Due to this reason, mocktail identified both events as different events.